# symmetricds 3.10.4 Push data from oracle to postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, symmetricds

I have 2 databases , 1 postgres (updated in corp-000.properties) and 1 oracle (updated in store-001.properties). Is there a way I can push data only from oracle to postgres ? Any parameter I should add in the properties file ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is, follow the quick start chapter from the guide to learn how to do it with an in-memory db and then the transition to oracle and postgres will be pretty simple. if there were any problems post a new question

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was able to manage the pushing of data from oracle to postgresql  by updating in sym_trigger_router.